# Is there a way in Anylogic to pick items from a rackSystem in a specific order?

Tags: anylogic

I am using a rack pick block to pick items stored in a rack system. I would like to have the worker picking the items, to select them according to the order of the pallet racks specified inside the rack system element.

For example:
If the rack system contains: palletRack10, palletRack9, ...
I would like the worker to pick all the items from palletRack 10, then from palletRack9 and so on.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to sort your product agents before they enter "RackPick". The entire library is order-centric, not resource-centric, so the orders ask resources to come pick them, not the other way around.

Put a queue before the "RackPick" and apply custom sorting that makes orders enter in the sequence you require. (The help explains how to do custom sorting).

Comment: I added it. The condition I added in the field "agent1 is preferred to agent2" in the queue block is: palletRack1.getCellOf(agent1).position>palletRack1.getCellOf(agent2).position

It is not working anyway... How can I solve it? It seems like it is not sorting and items are being picked like no queue block is inserted.

Comment: This is a different question, please create a new question (and phrase it from scratch so others can understand it as well, add screenshots...). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask